# Robot framework resource file not found

Tags: testing, robotframework

I want to use a resource file with the name clean_environment.robot on windows. It is in the same folder like my robot file (C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\git\src), which is callig the resource file.

Basic file 30.robot:

```
** Settings **
Resource    clean_environment.robot

** Test Cases **
MyTestCase
    Clean environment
```

I get the error:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file
'C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\git\src\30.robot': 
Resource file 'Clean environment' does not exist.
```

The resource file:

```
*** Settings ***

*** Test Cases ***
Clean environment
    Log to console    111
```

Edit:
The computer said: Resource file 'Clean environment' does not exist! But 'Clean environment is not the resource file, it is the keyword right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file has a test case in it, it is not considered to be a resource  file by robot. Resource files can only have keywords, variables and settings.

If you expect `Clean environment` to be a keyword, put it in a keyword table:

```
*** Keywords ***
Clean environment
    Log to console    1111
```

Comment: I tried this before but something didn't work. I don't know the reason. But it is working now. Thanks!